# How can I fetch a remote file in php over ssh and return file directly to the browser response without creating a copy of the file on the webserver

Tags: php, ssh, scp

I am currently using a similar version of the below code to transfer a file from a remote server to my web server and then redirecting to the web server copy of the file in a publicly accessible web location.

```
$tempfile = "/mylocalfolder/tempfile.wav" 

if (file_exists($tempfile)) {
        unlink($tempfile);
    }

$selectedfile = htmlspecialchars($_GET["File"]);
$filelink = '/myremotefolder/'.$selectedfile;

$connection = ssh2_connect($remote_server_ip, 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

//echo $filelink.','. $tempfile;
ssh2_scp_recv($connection, $filelink, "/mylocalfolder/tempfile.wav");

header( 'Location: /mylocalfolder/recording.wav' ) ;
```

I also get some files from amazon s3 using their api. When i use this method the api returns the file as an object so I am able to send it directly to the browser with the appropriate headers. like below example.

```
// Display the object in the browser
header("Content-Type: {$result['ContentType']}");
header("Content-Type: audio/wav");
echo $result['Body'];
}
```

My question is how can stream/get a file from a remote server and send it to the browser in the same way as the bottom version without creating a physical copy on the webserver.  Many thanks in advance

Comment: Essentially you already are creating a local copy (in your browsers memory), you just aren't saving it to disk.

Comment: Sorry when i refer to local copy I mean on the webserver.  So the file isn't created physically on the webserver.

Comment: I have edited the question thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to stream the file, or have the client save it?

Comment: Initially stream but i would like the option to download also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ssh2_sftp http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php ... you must install ssh2 bindings as PECL extension (http://php.net/manual/es/book.ssh2.php)

An example code may be ...

```
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$remote = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/path/to/file", 'rb');

header( 'Content-type: ......');

while(!feof($remote)){
    echo( fread($remote, 4096));
}
```

I have not tested the code, but it should work.

Comment: The second parameter is $length. According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php : Up to length number of bytes read. You can use 4096 * n if you want transmit more data in each block.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) to download the file:

```
require_once 'Net/SFTP.php';

$connection = new Net_SFTP($remote_server_ip);
if (!$connection->login('username', 'password')) die('Login Error');

// set some appropriate content headers
echo $connection->get($filelink);
```

Or you can use the `ssh2.sftp` wrapper - see SilvioQ's answer for that approach.

Comment: This looks great but I cannot get it to work with a non standard port i have tried Net_SFTP($remote_server_ip, 1234) as per the docs but it always tries port 22.